# Rails 2 support after Rails 3 has been released

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there some plan or estimate about how long will Rails 2 be supported after Rails 3 has been released?

I wanted to ride the wave and move to Rails 3 right away, specially for projects that may take 4 or 6 months to finish (so that they would probably be released with Rails 3.0.0 final) but I've found many things still not working, many basic plugins and gems; so I believe I'm stuck with Rails 2 for now.

Comment: For future searchers, there's a company commercially supporting rails 2.3: railslts.com which will also be releasing their updates as OSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be fine with Rails 2.3.x for awhile now.  Rails 3 is still in beta and the 2.3 branch will receive security updates for awhile (after Rails 3 is released) before it's abandoned by the core team.

Comment: You know if a while is tow weeks, two months, two years?

Comment: At least a year. Keep in mind that it's still in beta, so you still have several months before 3.0 is even released.  2.3 is still the stable way to go, you shouldn't feel bad about starting an app on 2.3.  Also, moving to 3.0 once it's polished really shouldn't be too bad, even on large projects.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 2 features such as ActiveRecord finder syntax, routing syntax etc. that are deprecated in Rails 3 are set to be removed in Rails 3.1 I believe.

Comment: See this blog post from Pratik Naik: http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/22/active-record-query-interface It states It states these deprecations will be effective in Rails’ 3.1 release (not Rails 3) and will be fully removed in Rails 3.2, though there will be an official plugin to continue supporting them.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Rails 4 is about to hit, official support for Rails 2 will definitely end. There is a commercial service ([railslts.com](http://railslts.com)) that will continue to provide security updates for Rails 2.3 applications.